# Extrude along normals not following slope

Tags: normals, extrude, transform-orientation

Can anyone advise me what I'm doing wrong here?

Following a tutorial where the ground layer has an incline of about 5 degrees. The layer above it is a face extruded in Z, duplicated from the ground and with a bevel on the corner vertex to create a curve.

I've duplicated the outer faces of this curve, separated by selection into a new object. What I'm trying to do is to extrude these faces along normals to create a outer pavement layer. In the tutorial I'm following these extruded faces follow the incline of the ground layer's slope. When I try to recreate this, they're following the global x and y axes.

I have already tried to change the rotation of the object, where transform affects only origins, but the results are the same. That said, I am a little bit unfamiliar with adjusting origin rotations.

[image: Ground layer with pavement layers above]

[image: Extrude along normals result]

[image: Attempt at correcting local rotation]

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: @Markus, thank you. Your explanation made a lot of sense, and worked for me. I knew there was some logical step I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If a normal isn't parallel to the slope, then extruding along the normal won't follow the slope. It seems your problem is that when you extruded part of the slope up, you limited the extrusion to Z axis, rather than extruding along the normal of the slope.

$\bbox[#FFDDDD, 7px]{\color{#880000}{\text{Bad:}}}$

[image]

$\bbox[#DDFFDD, 7px]{\color{#006600}{\text{Good:}}}$

[image]

BTW, you probably want to use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (*Extrude Manifold*) in this case...

$\bbox[#FFFFBB, 7px]{\color{#444400}{\text{Recovering:}}}$

You can still recover from the situation you're in, by setting the slope to a custom orientation and extruding along X or Y axis of that orientation:

[image]